# No view found for id 0x7f0e006c, load different fragment in ViewPager which is in CustomDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am loading viewpager in Dialogbox, Viewpager contain different fragments

below is my code for dialog box

```
 public void openFillUpInformationDialog(){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_filling_form);

        _mViewPager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
        _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
        _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        dialog.show();
    }
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context _context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        _context=context;

    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Form 1 will loaded");
                f= LayoutOne.newInstance(_context);<------I am getting error over here
                break;
            case 1:
                f= LayoutTwo.newInstance(_context);
                break;
        }
        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

LayoutOne.java is

```
public class LayoutOne extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        LayoutOne f = new LayoutOne();

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_form, null);
        return root;
    }

}
```

I have googled so many times but still not able to resolve my issue, please if any help me.

layout file for **first_form.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Form - 1"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


</LinearLayout>
```

LayoutFile for **Custom_dialog_filling_form.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="1134dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Previouse"
            android:id="@+id/btnPreviouse"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My LogCat Detail is

```
10-06 10:58:13.954 11897-11897/com.mapexample I/System.out: Form 1 will loaded
10-06 10:58:13.956 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0e006c (com.mapexample:id/viewPager) for fragment LayoutOne{12db1cc8 #1 id=0x7f0e006c android:switcher:2131624044:0}
10-06 10:58:13.956 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
10-06 10:58:13.956 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:   Local FragmentActivity 14c06161 State:
10-06 10:58:13.956 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
10-06 10:58:13.956 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     mLoadersStarted=true
10-06 10:58:13.956 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:   Active Fragments in 259b3486:
10-06 10:58:13.956 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     #0: NavigationDrawerFragment{32ba6147 #0 id=0x7f0e0067}
10-06 10:58:13.956 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#7f0e0067 mContainerId=#0 mTag=null
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mState=5 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=true mInLayout=true
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{259b3486 in MainActivity{14c06161}}
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mActivity=com.mapexample.MainActivity@14c06161
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{26e93d74 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0067 app:id/fragment_drawer}
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mInnerView=android.widget.LinearLayout{26e93d74 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0067 app:id/fragment_drawer}
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       Child FragmentManager{1dc0b29d in NavigationDrawerFragment{32ba6147}}:
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:         FragmentManager misc state:
10-06 10:58:13.957 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:           mActivity=com.mapexample.MainActivity@14c06161
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:           mContainer=android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1@23e61312
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:           mParent=NavigationDrawerFragment{32ba6147 #0 id=0x7f0e0067}
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:           mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     #1: LayoutOne{12db1cc8 #1 id=0x7f0e006c android:switcher:2131624044:0}
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#7f0e006c mContainerId=#7f0e006c mTag=android:switcher:2131624044:0
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mState=1 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:1 mBackStackNesting=0
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
10-06 10:58:13.958 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{259b3486 in MainActivity{14c06161}}
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mActivity=com.mapexample.MainActivity@14c06161
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     #2: LayoutTwo{34b1cae3 #2 id=0x7f0e006c android:switcher:2131624044:1}
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#7f0e006c mContainerId=#7f0e006c mTag=android:switcher:2131624044:1
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mState=0 mIndex=2 mWho=android:fragment:2 mBackStackNesting=0
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=false mHasMenu=false
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=false
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{259b3486 in MainActivity{14c06161}}
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:   Added Fragments:
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     #0: NavigationDrawerFragment{32ba6147 #0 id=0x7f0e0067}
10-06 10:58:13.959 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     #1: LayoutOne{12db1cc8 #1 id=0x7f0e006c android:switcher:2131624044:0}
10-06 10:58:13.960 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     #2: LayoutTwo{34b1cae3 #2 id=0x7f0e006c android:switcher:2131624044:1}
10-06 10:58:13.960 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:   FragmentManager misc state:
10-06 10:58:13.960 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     mActivity=com.mapexample.MainActivity@14c06161
10-06 10:58:13.960 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@2a16bce0
10-06 10:58:13.960 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
10-06 10:58:13.960 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:   View Hierarchy:
10-06 10:58:13.960 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{e7adb99 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-06 10:58:13.961 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:       android.widget.LinearLayout{a8e4e5e V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-06 10:58:13.961 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{152c323f G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020373}
10-06 10:58:13.961 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:         android.widget.FrameLayout{16dac70c V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-06 10:58:13.961 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:           android.support.v7.internal.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout{23149855 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0050 app:id/action_bar_root}
10-06 10:58:13.961 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.internal.widget.ViewStubCompat{1cecf26a G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0051 app:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
10-06 10:58:13.964 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout{2abbb35b V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
10-06 10:58:13.964 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:               android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{35f347f8 VFE..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0064 app:id/drawer}
10-06 10:58:13.964 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:                 android.widget.LinearLayout{3a5364d1 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-06 10:58:13.964 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:                   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{8dfcb36 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0065 app:id/toolbar_actionbar}
10-06 10:58:13.964 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.TextView{18f82a37 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-06 10:58:13.964 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:                   android.widget.FrameLayout{1c10eba4 V.E...C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0066 app:id/container}
10-06 10:58:13.964 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:                 android.widget.LinearLayout{26e93d74 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0067 app:id/fragment_drawer}
10-06 10:58:13.965 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:                   android.widget.RelativeLayout{3fd87d0d V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0e007e app:id/navigationHeader}
10-06 10:58:13.965 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.ImageView{2a5564c2 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-06 10:58:13.965 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/FragmentManager:                   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{3b1b32d3 VFED.VC. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0e007f app:id/drawerList}
10-06 10:58:13.971 11897-11897/com.mapexample D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mapexample, PID: 11897
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e006c (com.mapexample:id/viewPager) for fragment LayoutOne{12db1cc8 #1 id=0x7f0e006c android:switcher:2131624044:0}
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1072)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:918)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1440)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1148)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-06 10:58:13.992 11897-11897/com.mapexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Please post the layouts as well

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast thanks for your reply, I am just updating that

Comment: Please add the full stack trace as well, i suspect this might be relating to nested fragments.